# How to use dash instead of point in captions and \numberwithin{figure}{section}

Tags: captions, numbering

My figures are numbered within sections. I want to use dash instead of point in figure captions (eg, Figure 1-1-3, Figure 2-7-1) and do not change the style of section headers (that is, remain the style like `1.1`, `1.2`, `2.3`). The following method fails. I would appreciate any help with this situation.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection-\arabic{figure}}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}



\begin{document}

\chapter{} 

\section{}

\section{}

The following caption should be Figure 1-2-1.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}


\section{}

The following caption should be Figure 1-3-1.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}

The following caption should be Figure 1-3-2.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}

The following caption should be Figure 1-3-3.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to `\numberwithin{figure}{section}` because this also redefines `\thefigure`. After that you can redefine `\thefigure` (again) to suit your needs. Explicitly use `\thechapter-\arabic{section}` to insert a `-` between those two elements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,caption}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter-\arabic{section}-\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\section{Another section}

The following caption should be Figure 1-2-1.
\begin{center}
  \captionof{figure}{A figure caption}
\end{center}

\section{Yet another section}

The following caption should be Figure 1-3-1.
\begin{center}
  \captionof{figure}{Another figure caption}
\end{center}

The following caption should be Figure 1-3-2.
\begin{center}
  \captionof{figure}{Yet another figure caption}
\end{center}

The following caption should be Figure 1-3-3.
\begin{center}
  \captionof{figure}{A final figure}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```